# How to extract qr code contents and store it as an array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, qr-code

I have this qr code content that I've extracted using QR scanner web application. Example below only.

**Example:**

```
// This is the string extracted from the QR Code
"Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7"
```

And I've assigned it to a variable when I submit it to store into my database

**PHP**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $qr_results = $_POST['qr_bookingresults'];
    $array_results = ltrim($qr_results,"QR Code:"); // I used ltrim because there is a string QR Code: attached when I extract the qr code

    echo $array_results;

  }


?>
```

But when I use `print_r function()` the string only stores in one array like this:

```
$fetchresult = array($array_results); // Assign variable and convert $array_results variable to an array
print_r($fetchresult);
```

**print_r() function Result**

```
Array ( [0] => "Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7" )
```

My question is, why is it only stores the whole string into one array? wherein it should be like this.

```
Array ( [0] => Name1 [1] => Name2 [2] => Name3 [3] => Name4 [4] => Name5 [5] => Name6 [6] => Name7 )
```

Because what I really want to do is extract the contents and store it into an array so that I can have the freedom to insert it into mysql like this:

```
// Assign each variable to an array for inserting into mysql
$name1 = $fetchresult[0];
$name2 = $fetchresult[1];
$name3 = $fetchresult[2];
$name4 = $fetchresult[3];
$name5 = $fetchresult[4];
$name6 = $fetchresult[5];
$name7 = $fetchresult[6];
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: [explode](http://php.net/explode) and one of the various methods to drop the `"`s

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a CSV formatted string.

Use [`str_get_csv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to make sure you account for any in-text commas and escaped quotes.

```
<?php
$qr_string = '"Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7","I am here to ruin your day, am I not?","24"" (inch) TV"';

$array = str_getcsv( $qr_string );

print_r( $array );
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Name1
    [1] => Name2
    [2] => Name3
    [3] => Name4
    [4] => Name5
    [5] => Name6
    [6] => Name7
    [7] => I am here to ruin your day, am I not?
    [8] => 24" (inch) TV
)
```

Comment: this worked also, but which is best? str_get_csv() or using explode function()

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano I think you have an opinion on that already. Which solution do you think will provide the most longevity and help you to avoid errors in the future?

Answer (score 0):

you need to split the string with `,`.use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode)

[**Sandbox**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5e47850fa9d3df8ae5fe35c19b5d8a1fbd10c51d)

```
$a = '"Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7"';
$arr = explode(',',$a);
print_r($arr);
```